# Cannot deploy my Quick 2 app to a Windows system without Qt installed

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am using Qt 5 with Visual Studio compiler. I have a Quick 2 application with a c++ backend.

I have bundled together my exe, a bunch of dll files, and *all* of the plugins from Qt, into a single folder. When I run the exe in this folder on a system with Qt installed but Qt Creator closed, it runs fine. When I run it on a system without Qt installed, it does not crash, but it just opens a small 1-inch square window that is all white, nothing else.

I am using a Qt resource file for the QML, so there are no standalone QML files that could be getting missed by the exe. Again, it runs fine on a system with Qt, so what else could I be missing? Dependency walker does not report any problems.

Here is what is in my app directory:

[image]

I've been looking at this for hours and I cannot understand what I must be missing (or why Windows deployment is so challenging with Qt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was resolved by also adding these directories:

[image]

Comment: your added image is not available

Comment: All images are displaying fine on my browser.

Comment: I tested chrome and safari nothing for me, is there setting for displaying